# convert String to ASCII and ASCII to String

Tags: java, string, ascii

This is my code to convert String to ASCII and ASCII to String. I have problem when the user enter text with spaces the all texts didn't convert but if i wrote the text in program the text converted . This is my input "Java is easy"

```
String str = input.next();
//String str = "Java is easy";

char ch[] = str.toCharArray();
int num[] = new int[str.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print((int)ch[i] + " ");
    num[i] = (int)ch[i];
}
System.out.println("");
for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
    System.out.print((char)num[j]);
}
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: So what happens? Where is code of reading user input?

Comment: Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: `String` and `char` are for UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. If you expect the subset of Unicode in common with ASCII, you have to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner.next()` reads a single word, i.e. "Java".

`Scanner.nextLine()` reads an entire line, i.e. "Java is easy"

You should change

```
String str = input.next();
```

to

```
String str = input.nextLine();
```